# Including an image in my RSS feed to Twitter via dlvr.it

Tags: php, twitter, rss

I have a feed which i schedule for delivery using dlvr.it every 6 hours. It contains tide times and a brief surf report. I'd also like to include the most recent image from our webcams. This is my updated version of the RSS feed to include the image URL but Twitter is not picking up the image

This is the feed now with included image tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://www.gowerlive.co.uk/twitterfeed-mumbles.php" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><channel>
<title>Mumbles.co.uk</title>
<link>http://www.mumbles.co.uk</link>
<description>The Definitive Guide to Mumbles</description>
<language>en</language>
<item>
<title>Tide Times for Mumbles</title>
<link>http://www.mumbles.co.uk/</link>
<description>Todays tides:L02:04 H08:21 L14:23 H20:42. @ 16:00 the buoy was 4ft@6secs | Wind:gentle SW@9mph. Visit http://www.mumbles.co.uk</description>
<image>
<url>http://www.gowerlive.co.uk/netcam.jpg</url>
<title>Langland Bay</title>
<link>http://www.gowerlive.co.uk/webcams/langland-webcam</link>
</image> 
<pubDate>Wed, 6 Jun 2012 16:34:00 GMT</pubDate>
<dc:creator>Mumbles.co.uk</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink='false'>Wed, 6 Jun 2012 16:34:00 GMT</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

thanks

Lee

Comment: How do you currently call the image? Or where is the image pulled from if not paired with the description?

Comment: The image is FTP'd to the server every few minutes and the old one is over written but has the same file name. I could add another element to the XML above containing the URL to the  but I don't know what to call it and cant find any documentation for it?